# Hide Something in Video in React

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, html5-video, react-player

I need to hide the icon encircled on the picture below? How can I hide it? I'm using `react-player`.
[image]

Pls check this codesandbox
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-player-forked-o99ht?file=/src/index.js)

```
<ReactPlayer
      url="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"
      playing={true}
      volume={1}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      controls
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 `<Video />` tag supports disabling this feature via the [`disablepictureinpicture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#disable_pip) attribute. This is still an experimental feature, and might not work in all browsers.

Pass the `disablePictureInPicture` html attribute via the ReactPlayer's config. If the Picture in Picture control doesn't disappear try setting `controlsList: 'nodownload'` as well.

```
const config = {
  attributes: {
    disablePictureInPicture: true,
    controlsList: 'nodownload'
  }
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <ReactPlayer
      url="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"
      playing={true}
      volume={1}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      config={config}
      controls
    />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hello there again. I've applied it in here https://codesandbox.io/s/video-player-with-slider-forked-comoz. On the first slider, it doesn't appear but on second one, it appears

Comment: It's an experimental feature. Updated answer to solve this one as well.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Ori

Comment: Hi again. I see errors in console for this. `Invalid DOM property disablepictureinpicture. Did you mean disablePictureInPicture`

Comment: I've changed the config to remove the warnings. See updated answer. You were right about the camel case. Also `true` should be a boolean, and not a string in this case.

Comment: Welcome again. That was educational for me as well :)